Changing Author Byline in Post-Meta by Active Page
I am using a newspaper style WordPress theme and the PublishPress Authors plugin. No issues there. ✅
The theme has a post-meta.php file which defines, obviously, how the post-meta is displayed on the page. I am trying to modify the author block of the post-meta to use the PublishPress Authors shortcode, dependent on the active page. For instance, on the home or front page, it should be using one style, but on the single-posts it should be using another.
I have tried a few different ways that I found browsing through StackOverflow, including an echo, but that seemed to cause the PublishPress Authors shortcode to show up in a weird and large overlapping position, over the existing post-meta.
My final attempt has been the following code:
    $author_link = '';

    if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
        $author_link = $author_img . $label . (!is_home() || !is_front_page() ? get_the_author_posts_link() : 
            do_shortcode('[publishpress_authors_box layout="ppma_boxes_1011" author_categories="author,co-author"]'));
    }
    elseif (is_single()) {
        $author_link = $author_img . $label . (!is_single() ? get_the_author_posts_link() : 
            do_shortcode('[publishpress_authors_box layout="ppma_boxes_1567"]'));
    }
    else {
        $author_link = $author_img . $label . (!is_home() || !is_front_page() || !is_single() ? get_the_author_posts_link() : 
            do_shortcode('[publishpress_authors_box layout="ppma_boxes_1011" author_categories="author,co-author"]'));
    }                                                      
                                                           
    $output = sprintf(
        '<span class="%1$s">%2$s</span>',
        esc_attr(join(' ', $classes)),
        $author_link
    );

I added the third else statement because I was not sure how to properly address all of the remaining categorized archive pages, so thought this might be a good approach.
What's strange, is the elseif statement seems to be working, but not the other two. I see the correct change on single-posts. I know I am missing something obvious and hope someone can point it out to me.
Thank you!
UPDATE 08/01/2024 9:55AM ET: I shortened the if statements to differentiate between just a page and a post. It seems to have had the desired effect on the home/front page and single-posts, but the archive pages (categories) erase the $author_link completely. 
Here is the code snippet:
    $author_link = '';

    if (is_page()) {
        $author_link = $author_img . $label . (!is_page() ? get_the_author_posts_link() : 
            do_shortcode('[publishpress_authors_box layout="ppma_boxes_1011" author_categories="author,co-author"]'));
    }
    elseif (is_single()) {
        $author_link = $author_img . $label . (!is_single() ? get_the_author_posts_link() : 
            do_shortcode('[publishpress_authors_box layout="ppma_boxes_1567"]'));
    }                                              
                                                           
    $output = sprintf(
        '<span class="%1$s">%2$s</span>',
        esc_attr(join(' ', $classes)),
        $author_link
    );

UPDATE 08/01/2024 10:04AM ET: Disregard the previous update. I cleared the cache and it is still not displaying correctly. 

Looks like I figured it out! After a full purge of the cache and changing from is_archive() to is_category(), all pages are now displaying the correct shortcode. Thanks to anyone who viewed this question. I appreciate your time.
